# Magnific popup doesn't display after navigating to other page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, magnific-popup

I'm running into a strange problem with Magnific popup. I have two separate pages with links to the same Magnific-enabled popups.

1. Click a magnific-enabled link on page 1--- popup comes up. Closing the popup and clicking again works fine too.
2. Click a link on page 1 to go to page 2.
3. Click a mangific-enabled link on page 2--- popup doesn't come up.
4. Reload the browser for page 2.
5. Click a magnific-enabled link on page 2--- popup comes up. Closing the popup and clicking again works fine too.
6. Click a link on page 2 to go to page 1.
7. Click a magnific-enabled link on page 1--- popup doesn't come up.
8. Reload the browser for page 1.
9. Click a magnific-enabled link on page 1--- popup comes up. Closing the popup and clicking again works fine too.
10. Repeat from step 2.

I have the `fixedContentPos` option set to `true` so the background doesn't scroll when the popup is up. In every instance I've outlined above where the popup *doesn't* come up, the background doesn't scroll *as if the popup were there*. I've looked in inspector, and see the `overflow:hidden` attribute attached that's stopping the background scroll. However, the popup DOM elements are not there.

This is a Rails site btw. I tested out the same Javascript code on a static version, and it works as intended, so I'm wondering if this has something to do with how Rails handles routing?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have Turbolinks enabled (it makes pages load faster by only replacing the  content but it's not triggering $(document).ready() )

You should bind your image links like this :

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function(event) {
  $('.test-popup-link').magnificPopup({ ...});
});
```

Or disable turbolinks

Comment: It looks like an issue with Turbolinks. Unfortunately `page:load` doesn't quite seem to do it, but now I've got a lead to follow up with. Thanks!